# Change taskbar location with powershell and autohide Windows 10 build 14393

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to place the taskbar location to the top with powershell and let it auto-hide.

I found this website with option three what works for most people. The only problem is I'm trying to get this fixed in Windows 10 build 14393.
https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1066-taskbar-move-location-desktop-screen.html

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2]
```

I came across one forum who told that it was changing a registry value. I tried to do so but it didn't work. When I changed the location to the top, I looked in the regedit again and the same value was still here.

Does anyone know the location of where the registry key is stored in?

```
$RegKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2"
$RegName = "Settings"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name $RegName -Value $RegValue
```

Does anyone knows what I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to autohide Windows 10 build 14393. You can change one registry key.
   [registry path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95j2T.png)
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\PaintDesktopVersion`

Change the registry key value 0.

2. Use PowerShell to change registry key value. I think you script is right.
   But your path is wrong. You can follow my path below.

   **`$RegKey = "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop"
   $RegName = "PaintDesktopVersion"
   Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name $RegName -Value 0`**

I hope can help you.

Comment: Sorry mate. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/drey/2011/03/28/paint-desktop-version-registry-key/ I just tested it and read some documentation about it. This is not to change the desktop start bar.